# Is it ok to use multi split function in one line?

Tags: python

I want to get the follow list:
**['value1', 'value2', 'value3']**
from the next string:
**some_option=value1,value2,value3**

Is it ugly to use the following code to get this?

```
some_string = 'some_option=value1,value2,value3'
print(some_string.split('=')[1].split(','))
```

Comment: It's fine if you don't need any of the other data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the "ugly" statement, as that seems perfectly Pythonic to me, and efficient enough for the job at least. IMHO the question of how the code appears  doesn't matter as much as whether it's easily *understandable* to others what the code is doing, and more importantly whether it actually gets the task accomplished - which it certainly does.

A slight change for optimization I would propose is to pass the number of splits to `str.split`, and then you can safely access the last result rather than the 2nd element:

```py
some_string = 'some_option=value1,value2,value3'

print(some_string.split('=', 1)[-1].split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

"Ugly" is a matter of opinion, and can not be answered on stackoverflow.

The real issue with your code however, is that it has no error checking, so if the input string does not contain an `=` character, you will be indexing a non-existent list member.

If this code is designed for production application and not some personal tool, you should do something like this:

```
some_string = 'some_option=value1,value2,value3'
try:
    print(some_string.split('=')[1].split(','))
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Or, if you just want to skip the bad strings you can put `pass` in the `except` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more context, it looks fine to me. If you feel bad about the ugliness, one way to improve might be to put that inside a function, such as

```
def scrape_values(row):
    return row.split('=')[1].split(',')


some_string = 'some_option=value1,value2,value3'
print(scrape_values(some_string))
```

If you give the function a meaningful name, then we can "abstract away" the ugliness

Comment: You should not name your parameter `str` as is will shadow the Python built in function.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it